# backbone fetch id changed

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

Has Model fetch behaviour, specifically setting the model id, changed between 1.1.0 and 1.1.2?

I've checked the changelog and can't find anything relevant.

The following no longer works:

```
var Wibble = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'rest/wibble',
    idAttribute: 'wibbleId'
 });

var model = new Wibble();
model.id = 1;
model.fetch()
```

It requests /rest/wibble rather than /rest/wibble/1 as it used to.

Examples: I've used url() rather than fetch() to demonstrate

[jsbin for 1.1.0](http://jsbin.com/zubidozurage/3/edit?html,js,console)

[jsbin for 1.1.2](http://jsbin.com/zubidozurage/2/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A model builds its url by appending `/[id]` when the model is not new :

```
url: function() {
  var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') ||
    _.result(this.collection, 'url') ||
    urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base.replace(/([^\/])$/, '$1/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
}
```

but it appears that `model.isNew` changed between 1.1.0 and 1.1.2

- [Backbone 1.1.0](https://rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/1.1.0/backbone.js)

  ```
  isNew: function() {
    return this.id == null;
  },
  ```
- [Backbone 1.1.2](https://rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/1.1.2/backbone.js)

  ```
  isNew: function() {
    return !this.has(this.idAttribute);
  },
  ```

The check now only considers the property described by `idAttribute` and no longer the `id` property.

Setting your `idAttribute` as you did in your 1.1.2 example is probably the safest bet:

```
model.set('wibbleId', 123);
```